# leptonica - get dimensions (height/width)

Tags: c++, leptonica

How to get height and width from a pix?

```
Pix *image = pixRead((input).c_str());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pixGetWidth](https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/leptprotos_8h.html#aa71e0b02548a56e723c76996ab145257) and [pixGetHeight](https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/leptprotos_8h.html#a511e60efcf1d9f3f59b5308ef5f49a06):

```
Pix *image = pixRead((input).c_str());
int width = pixGetWidth(image);
int height = pixGetHeight(image);
```